# RegAsm: Warning RA0000: Could not load file or assembly 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common Version=17.0.54.0?

Tags: c#, autocad

I have created one .net COM dll which refer Autocad files. While i try to Register that Dll in Client Pc an error Occurred like this.

[image]**RegAsm: Warning RA0000: Could not load file or assembly 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common, Version=17.0.54.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eed84259d7cbf30b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Below i have mentioned my reference Dll's snap and error snap while i try to register the COM Dll in my PC.  **[image]

Any body can help me to solve this problem.  Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Thanks for your information it is not only warning below the warning an error occurred. See RegAsm : error RA0000..

Comment: Well, where is it?  Did you try running Regasm.exe from your build directory?  How did this DLL end up in c:\program files instead of your project's build directory?

Comment: sorry for the improper information. i have hidden my company name and product name for some security purpose. But while i am try to register my dll i have given the full path(with company name and product name) only.